# Cannot find Makefile flags c++ OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

I am very new to makefiles, I have downloaded open source code for Super Resolution in OpenCV, and it comes with this makefile:

```
INCLUDE=-I/usr/include/opencv
 FLAGS=-lml -lcvaux -lhighgui -lcv -lcxcore
 LIBS=-L/usr/lib
 main:
     g++ -o main *.cpp ${INCLUDE} ${LIBS} ${FLAGS}
```

When I run `make`, none of the flags are found, all generating error messages as such

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lml
```

Am I missing some files? Am I using the makefile wrong?

Comment: `cannot find -lml` indicates that your flags are working, and that the problem is that the library search path is incomplete.  I guess you'll want to update the `-L` option to include the pertinent directory.

Comment: Ok thanks I will give that a go

Comment: @tripleee do you know what the default filepath for opencv libraries is when using sudo apt-get to install it

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libopencv-core2.3/filelist suggests `/usr/lib` if Ubuntu is your platform, but the error message is for `ml`.